# How to exclude the google cloud "message" log from opentelemetry java agent

Tags: elasticsearch, open-telemetry, google-cloud-sdk

I have run the spring boot application with opentelemetry java agent, and like to disable the logs sent by opentelemetry. I tried the `otel.metrics.exporter=none` but logs keep sent by google cloud libraries.

Is there a way to avoid sent those logs from google cloud libraries?

```bash
java \
    -javaagent:/opentelemetry-javaagent.jar \
    -Dotel.exporter.otlp.endpoint=${OTLP_URL} \
    -Dotel.exporter.otlp.headers="${OTLP_AUTH}" \
    -Dotel.metrics.exporter=otlp \
    -Dotel.logs.exporter=none \
    -Dotel.resource.attributes="service.name=${SERVICE_NAME},service.version=0.0.1,deployment.environment=${PROFILE}" \
    -Dspring.profiles.active=${PROFILE} \
    -jar /aura-mhi-backend.jar
```

- Telemetry sent to Elastic APM
- com.google.cloud:google-cloud-firestore:3.15.7
- com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub:4.8.4

screenshot of pubsub logs
[image: google cloud pubsub]

screenshot of firestore logs
[image: google cloud firestore]